# jquery onClick dynamically loading an image and fading it in

Tags: jquery, dynamic, fadein

I'm trying to dynamically load an image into a div by clicking on another div.  I'm trying to use the div's id to call the matching photo and then have it fade in.

I can't quite get it working, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X82zY/36/

and I'll also put the code here

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="preload" onload="fadeIn(this)" src="#" style="display:none;" />
</div>

<div id="TDodd" class="iso"></div>
```

JS

```
function fadeIn() {
    $(this).fadeIn(1000);
}

$(".iso").click(function() {

  var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#container 
img').attr('src','http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/instruments/violins/full/' + id + '.jpg');

    fadeIn();

});
```

Thanks for any help I can get here.

Comment: on `$('.iso")` you have a single quote starting and a double quote ending, is that a typo or is that your issue?

Comment: so I'm not sure how to define the fadeIn function due to it being inline.  Not sure how else to fade the image in onload though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error:

```
$('.iso').click(function() {
       ^
```

You can also get your elements by `id` and not by `class`.
Other problem is that your content is being dynamically created, so you have to use `on` instead, and bind the event to the document.

So your code should be:

```
$(document).on('click', '#TDodd', function() {
  var id = this.id;
  $('#preload').prop('src', 'http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/instruments/violins/full/' + id + '.jpg');

  fadeIn('#TDodd');
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/X82zY/42/)

Comment: but getting it by class is okay too right?  There are just going to be more then one button is all.

Comment: @loriensleafs Ah bom, it's just a typo, so it's right to use class.

Comment: thanks so much for helping me with this, really appreciate it!

Comment: quick question, if button container was contained in another div, and you wanted to get that div's ID for the variable, how would you do that?

Comment: @loriensleafs You can use the same code. As you can see, it works.

Comment: sorry that was unclear of me, I meant how could you use the id of the containing div by clicking on the contained div.

Comment: @loriensleafs `$(this).parent().prop('id');`

Comment: hey I have a question about something similar to this, can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things wrong:

1.) Your fiddle was not bound to the load function.

2.) The already pointed out quote mismatch on the .iso selector

3.) The fadeIn method call inside the click event.

The final js should look like this:

```
function fadeIn(obj) {
    $(obj).fadeIn(1000);
}

$('.iso').click(function()
{
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#container img').attr('src','http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/instruments/violins/full/' + id + '.jpg');

    fadeIn($('#container img'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X82zY/40/

Comment: is there an advantage using attr over prop used in the other working example given?  They just seem to be very similar and I was wondering if one was better than the other for any reason?

Comment: In this case, no prop and attr will get you the same value.  Prop will sometimes return a different value than attr.  In the case of checkboxes, if you `attr("checked")` it will return `checked`, where if you `prop("checked")` it will return `true`.